# want to the change in tailwind css to className css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to change tailwind css to className css could you tell me how to do it.

```
<div className={`${showpopup === "hide" ? "hidden" : "absolute"} `}>
          <Popup setshowpopup={setshowpopup} doc_id={docID} rating={rating} />
        </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: we want to add a specfic css in index.css and put on under className. for example - .Siderbar{ postion:absloute} .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the build tool, you can still import index.css, give it a className, and the style will override the tailwindcss，like：

```js
import ‘index.css’
```

If you just want to say how to add a file with custom css using a class name, I guess so

Comment: Could you tell me how to add className in div tag ?

Comment: Just add it. I don't know what you mean